# CCC-GARCH using a multivariate t-distribution

Tags: distributions, estimation, maximum-likelihood, garch, volatility-forecasting

The CCC-GARCH model is the simplest of all available multivariate volatility models. The covariance matrix is constructed as $D_tRD_t$ with $D_t$ a diagonal matrix with the standard deviations obtained from a univariate volatility model and $R$ corresponds to the unconditional correlation matrix of the standardised residuals.

This unconditional correlation matrix is often estimated by the sample correlation matrix (albeit that it is divided by $T$ instead of the unbiased $T-1$).

If a CCC-GARCH model is estimated using a multivariate $t$-distribution, how can one calculate the $R$ matrix? Is it for example allowed to just take the scale parameter of the multivariate $t$-distribution, calculate the covariance matrix and transform it into a correlation matrix and then take this correlation matrix as your $R$?

Comment: The scale matrix of a multivariate $t$ distribution does not generally satisfy the properties of a correlation matrix, e.g. that the elements are between -1 and 1, or does it? So the answer to your second question is likely a "No".

Comment: True, but the covariance matrix of the multivariate t-distribution can be transformed into a correlation matrix by dividing the covariances with the corresponding variances. Thereby, a correlation matrix can be obtained and this correlation matrix may be used for the CCC-GARCH. So, my question should have been, is one allowed to use this correlation matrix for a CCC-GARCH when using a multivariate t-distribution.

Comment: You could update your post including this information. It will be easier to notice and there will be no need to read the comments to find the real question.